# How to prevent Nginx from listening to port 80

Tags: nginx

I am using Nginx for routing port 8545 to 8845. Here is my `default.conf` file:

```
server {
  listen 8545;
  listen [::]:8545;
  server_name 194.***.***.***;
  location / {
    auth_basic "protected gateway area";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/apache2/.htpasswd;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8845;
    proxy_read_timeout 600s;
  }
}
```

However, somehow Nginx still listens to port 80. I want to use port 80 for something else. Why does Nginx listen to 80 and how do I prevent it?

Here is `sudo netstat -ltupn` output (trimmed)

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
...
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8545            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      195197/nginx: maste
...
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      195197/nginx: maste
...
tcp6       0      0 :::8545                 :::*                    LISTEN      195197/nginx: maste
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      195197/nginx: maste
...
```

Comment: Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files, and check for any other `server` blocks.

Comment: Thank you @RichardSmith for the suggestion. It helped. There were other conf files there by default. Removing them solved the problem.